# Librosa load not working when worked with WebAudio API

Tags: flask, web-audio-api, librosa

I have created front-end code that records audio using the Web Audio API and sends audio chunk blobs to the Flask backend every second.

```
public startRecording(): void {
        try {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
            .then((stream: MediaStream) => {
                this.mediaStream = stream;
                this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

                // Save audio data into chunks as it's being recorded
                this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", (event: any) => {
                    const blob = new Blob([event.data], { type: 'audio/wav' });

                    let formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append('audio', blob);

                    fetch('http://localhost:8000/detect_onset', {
                        mode: 'no-cors',
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: formData
                    }).then((response) => {
                        console.log(response);
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        console.error(error);
                    });
                });
                // Send a `dataavailable` event every 1s
                this.mediaRecorder.start(1000);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
```

I then use Librosa on the back end to load the audio and attempt to do onset detection.

```
@app.route('/detect_onset', methods=['POST'])
def detect_onset():
    audio_file = request.files.get('audio')
    y, sr = librosa.load(audio_file)
    # ... (onset detection code)
```

However, the `librosa.load` function is not working because the audio_file format is not recognized.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When using the built-in `MediaRecorder` of the browser the `mimeType` will never be `'audio/wav'`. Every browser defaults to another format but non of them supports `'audio/wav'`.

There is also no need to wrap the `data` property of the `'dataavailable'` event in another `Blob`. It should already be a `Blob` with the correct `type`.

But when calling `start()` with an argument (`1000` in your code above) it will emit multiple `'dataavailable'` events. It will emit about one event every 1000 milliseconds. These events contain a part of the final file. But these parts are not required to be valid files on their own.

The easiest way to avoid getting partial content is by calling `start()` without any argument.

In case the build-in formats of the `MediaRecorder` don't work with your backend you could also try to record wav files by using a library like [extendable-media-recorder](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/extendable-media-recorder).